# referencing tables in restructuredtext

Tags: restructuredtext

Is there anyway to refer a table in RestructuredText? something like 
see table `referencetable`_ 

(I saw some workarounds for referencing figures. couldn't find a way to refer a table though .. )

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply define a [hyperlink target](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#internal-hyperlink-targets).

```
Here is table-1_.

.. _table-1:

+------------+------------+-----------+
| Header 1   | Header 2   | Header 3  |
+============+============+===========+
| body row 1 | column 2   | column 3  |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| body row 2 | Cells may span columns.|
+------------+------------+-----------+
| body row 3 | Cells may  | - Cells   |   
+------------+ span rows. | - contain |
| body row 4 |            | - blocks. |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Or use the [table directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table) with the :name: option.